# Currying-in function and ES6 destructing

Tags: javascript, currying, destructuring

I was testing some currying-in function and I could get this to work pretty easily:

```
test = (a) => { return (b) => a+b } // test(5)(6) => 11
```

I couldn't get to work the same function when using the ES6 destructing argument:

```
test = ({a}) => { return (b) => a+b } // test(5)(6) => NaN
```

Is there a way to have it work? Why doesn't the second test function work?

Comment: Destructuring doesn't make sense when you want to handle a single argument.

Comment: Little off topic: You can also write `test = (a) => (b) => a + b`

Comment: Or if you want to use destructuring, `test = ([a,b]) => a+b`, called as `test([4,5])` (Magus is using currying)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use a destructuring argument, you have to call your function with an object :

```
test = ({a}) => { return (b) => a+b }
console.log(test({a : 5})(6)); // => 11
```

Comment: Thanks that was a big distraction on my side!